# How do I create a condition with my script using the if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, pine-script, indicator

I'm faced with a little challenge with the if statements. I want the codes (plotchar) below to be plotted only if the code (plotshape) is false. If the code (plotshape) is true, then code (plotchar) shouldn't be plotted.

```
plotshape (show_atr_rule ? atrchecklocation : na, style=shape.circle, location=absolute, size=tiny, color=color.yellow, transp=20)
```

```
plotchar(codiff_long, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, text="BUY", transp=0)
plotchar(codiff_short, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, text="SELL", transp=0)
```

Comment: What is this code and what is it meant to do? Assuming you're not looking for `if plotshape: ` but could you clarify what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ternary condition inside the `series` argument of the `plotchar` function, the same way you did with the `plotshape`:

```
plotshape (show_atr_rule ? atrchecklocation : na, style=shape.circle, location=absolute, size=tiny, color=color.yellow, transp=20)

plotchar(show_atr_rule  ? na : codiff_long, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, text="BUY", transp=0)
plotchar(show_atr_rule  ? na : codiff_short, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar, text="SELL", transp=0)
```